# Execute code php the function eval()

Tags: php, function, eval

The question is how to make it work the code that I have, since my code does not currently work.

Code:

```
$v = 4667033;
$g = " $v != 0 ";
$exp = "if( \{$g}\ ){ echo 'si'; }else{ echo 'no'; }";
$micadena =  $exp;

ob_start();
eval("\$micadena");
$this_string = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo "sdsdsd >>> ".$this_string;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: as I do that this code works is only one example, nose if there are other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your question is not clear you can try this instead

```
$v = 4667033;
$g = " $v != 0 "; $exp = "if( $g ){ echo 'si'; }else{ echo 'no'; }";
$micadena = $exp;
ob_start(); eval("$micadena"); $this_string = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean();
echo "sdsdsd >>> ".$this_string;
```

**Output**

`sdsdsd >>> si`